How to perform model comparison based on multinom( ) function of nnet package in R?
My independent variables are gender and sequence, and the dependent variable is intervention (including 3 intervention methods). I established a multinomial logistic regression model to examine the impact of gender and sequence on intervention. The main steps are:
I first use the multinom() function to establish a null model, then establish a full model, and then use the anova() function to compare the models.
The code is as follows:
model_null<-  multinom(intervention~ 1,data = test_data)
model_full<- multinom(intervention~ 1+ gender+sequence,data = test_data)
anova(model_full,model_null,test = "Chisq")

The result output is as follows:
enter image description here
I have two questions: 1.I am not sure if this analysis method is correct, because this is my first time using multinomial logistic regression. Since linear regression generally uses this method for model comparison, I adopted this method; 2.If it is correct, I don’t know how to get the chi-square value for model comparison. The current output result does not have a chi-square value, only a P value.
If you could give me some help, I would be very grateful~~
